# Telebot. Ошибка синтаксического анализа встроенной клавиатуры

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

Пишу телеграмм бота используя telebot и выходит такая ошибка:

`Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: can't parse inline keyboard button: Text buttons are unallowed in the inline keyboard"`

При чему выходит она только когда перехожу на кнопки с `def plato_delay`. Именно на эту часть кода ругаются. Посмотрел в интернете, перебробывал, но ничего не нашел. Уменьшал количество кнопок-не работает. Добавлял `bot.polling(none_stop=true)-` не работает. Писал  кнопки через []-не работает. Подскажите, что я делаю не так?

```
bot = telebot.TeleBot('token')
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def button(message):
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
    item = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Купить', callback_data='buy')
    item2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Продать', callback_data='sell')
    markup.add(item, item2)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '''Приветствую, это быстрый мониторинг-бот, которые найдет для вас самое выгодное предложение в один клик!''', reply_markup=markup)


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data in ['buy', 'sell', 'back'])
def bot_message(call):
    if call.data == 'buy':
        markup2 = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
        item3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('RUB(Рубль)', callback_data='rub')
        item4 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('KZT(Тенге)', callback_data='kzt')
        item5 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('THB(Бат)', callback_data='thb')
        markup2.add(item3, item4, item5)
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id,  'Вы хотите купить криптовалюту.Выберите валюту оплаты', reply_markup= markup2)
    elif call.data == 'sell':
        markup3 = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
        item6 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('BTC(Биткоин)', callback_data='btc')
        item7 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('USDT(Стейблкоин)', callback_data='usdt')
        item8 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('ETH(Эфириум)', callback_data='eth')
        item9 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('BNB(Бинанс коин)', callback_data='bnb')
        item10 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('USDC(Стейблкоин)', callback_data='usdc')
        markup3.add(item6, item7, item8, item9, item10)
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id,' Выберите криптовалюту для продажи', reply_markup= markup3)

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data in ['rub','kzt', 'thb'])
def call_message(call1):
    if call1.data == 'kzt':
        markup4 = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
        item11 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('BTC(Биткоин)', callback_data='btckzt')
        item12 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('USDT(Стейблкоин)', callback_data='usdtkzt')
        item13 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('ETH(Эфириум)', callback_data='ethkzt')
        item14 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('BNB(Бинанс коин)', callback_data='bnbkzt')
        item15 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('USDC(Стейблкоин)', callback_data='usdckzt')
        markup4.add(item11, item12, item13, item14, item15)
        bot.send_message(call1.message.chat.id,  'Выберите валюту', reply_markup = markup4)
    elif call1.data == 'rub':
        markup5 = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
        item16 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('BTC(Биткоин)', callback_data='btcrub')
        item17 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('USDT(Стейблкоин)', callback_data='usdtrub')
        item18 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('ETH(Эфириум)', callback_data='ethrub')
        item19 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('BNB(Бинанс коин)', callback_data='bnbrub')
        item20 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('USDC(Стейблкоин)', callback_data='usdcrub')
        markup5.add(item16, item17, item18, item19, item20)
        bot.send_message(call1.message.chat.id,' Выберите криптовалюту', reply_markup= markup5)
    elif call1.data == 'thb':
        markup6 = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
        item21 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('BTC(Биткоин)', callback_data='btckzt')
        item22 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('USDT(Стейблкоин)', callback_data='usdtkzt')
        item23 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('ETH(Эфириум)', callback_data='ethkzt')
        item24 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('BNB(Бинанс коин)', callback_data='bnbkzt')
        item25 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('USDC(Стейблкоин)', callback_data='usdckzt')
        markup6.add(item21, item22, item23, item24, item25)
        bot.send_message(call1.message.chat.id, 'Выберите валюту', reply_markup=markup6)


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data in ['btcrub'])
def plato_delay(call):
    if call.data == 'btcrub':
        markup7 = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
        item26 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Сбербанк', callback_data='buybtcrub_sber')
        item27 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Тинькофф', callbach_data='buybtcrub_tnkf')
        item28 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Альфабанк', callback_data='buybtcrub-alfa')
        item29 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('ВТБ', callback_data='buybtcrub_vtb')
        item30 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Наличные ДОЛЛАР', callback_data='buybtcrub_nalusd')
        item31 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Наличные РУБЛИ', callback_data='buybtcrub_nalrub')
        markup7.add(item26, item27, item28, item29)
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Выберите способ оплаты', reply_markup=markup7)



@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data in ['buybtcrub_sber','buybtcrub_tnkf'])
def vse_vse(call):
    if call.data == 'buybtcrub_sber':
        markup8 = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
        item32 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Купить', callback_data='buybtcrub_sber1')
        markup8.add(item32)
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, f'''Купить Биткоин за Рубли через СБЕРБАНК 
        Стоимость: {int(float(out_btc_sber))} Минимум: {min_btc_sber}''', reply_markup=markup8)

bot.polling()
```

Comment: В какой строке ошибка?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас ошибка в этом месте

```
item27 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Тинькофф', callbach_data='buybtcrub_tnkf')
```

Делайте  так

```
item27 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Тинькофф', callback_data='buybtcrub_tnkf')
```

Comment: Вы самый лучший, спасибо большое.